# iPhone CurrentTimeZoneOffset from UTC

Tags: iphone, datetime, timezone, offset, gmt

Is there a way to get the offset time zone for a given date.

For example, if I am in New York and I pass in 12-12-2009 4 PM I would get back "-4" as we are 4 hours off GMT.

(In .NET land there is a function to do that off the DateTime class. So I'm guess Cocoa has it too?)

Ian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
[[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone] secondsFromGMTForDate:someDate];
```

This will return the offset in seconds.

See Apple's documentation on the [NSTimeZone class](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution in Swift for getting time offset in String

https://gist.github.com/MihaelIsaev/35be147af2bb397d2cf8